# Why does this C code crash?

Tags: c, function, pointers, crash, strchr

Can someone explain to me why this code is constantly crashing.
Everything seems fine to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* find(char *haystack, char needle);
int main (){
    char haystack[400], needle;
    fgets(haystack,400,stdin);
    scanf("%c", needle);
    if(find(haystack,needle)) printf("%ld", find(haystack, needle) - haystack);
    else printf(NULL);
    return 0;
}
char* find(char *haystack, char needle) {
    int lewski, cska;
    lewski = strlen(haystack);
    if(strchr(haystack,needle)){
        cska = lewski-strlen(strchr(haystack,needle));
        return &haystack[cska];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You could run in a debugger and find out yourself.

Comment: "Why does this C code crash?" - I would assume because there is a programming error in the code. If you told where and when it crashes, along with the **expected** behaviour, it might be easier to help you. See [ask].

Comment: You want to enable all compiler warnings, then take the warnings issued serious and fix the code.

Comment: Also `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: And if supported by your C implementation use the length modifier `t` leading to `"%td"` to print out a pointer difference. This way you make sure the correct width for pointers is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not using `scanf` properly.
Modify as follows;

```
scanf("%c", &needle);
```

Also `printf` doesn't print `NULL`
Modify as follows;

```
printf("NULL");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: scanf("%c", &needle);
    else printf(-1);